# Java Audio Streaming - Mp3 Audio file in FireFox won't play

Tags: java, firefox, mp3, audio-streaming, outputstream

I recently created a Java program to stream MP3 audio using a servletOutputStream to the browser. I tested it on Firefox, chrome & IE, and it worked fine until I updated Firefox to the newest version (15.0.1). At first I thought this was because this new version of FireFox included the new version of Flash but I checked Chrome and IE and they were both using the latest version of Flash as well. Does anyone know why the newest version of Firefox would cause audio streaming to stop working? No error is thrown, it just wont play. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: how did you implement it on client side? flash player, html5?

Answer (score 0):

We're having the samt issue with a music player that used to both load and play mp3-files flawlessly until upgrading the Flash player from 11.2.x to 11.4.x.

This currently **only affects Firefox** since both IE and Google Chrome still seems to be using previous versions of the Flash player (11.3.x and 11.2.x respectively).

We're loading the music using two simple lines of code

```
var player:Sound = new Sound();
player.loadSound(filepath, true);
```

I can see that file gets loaded on the progressbar but it just won't start playing.

This of course does not help you solve your problem, but hopefully the additional info is importance to anyone else who is more of an Flash expert.

Comment: I've noticed if you downgrade your flash player to 10.3.183.25 Firefox will work again. There must be a bug with the new FireFox using the new version of Flash.